# Deadlock avoidance using scoped_lock

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm testing out some example code in the Galowicz C++17 book, listed below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono_literals;

mutex mut_a;
mutex mut_b;

static void deadlock_func_1() {
  cout << "bad f1 acquiring mutex A..." << endl;
  lock_guard<mutex> la{mut_a};
  this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
  cout << "bad f1 acquiring mutex B..." << endl;
  lock_guard<mutex> lb{mut_b};
  cout << "bad f1 got both mutexes." << endl;
}
static void deadlock_func_2() {
  cout << "bad f2 acquiring mutex B..." << endl;
  lock_guard<mutex> lb{mut_b};
  this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
  cout << "bad f2 acquiring mutex A..." << endl;
  lock_guard<mutex> la{mut_a};
  cout << "bad f2 got both mutexes." << endl;
}

static void sane_func_1() {
  scoped_lock l{mut_a, mut_b};
  cout << "sane f1 got both mutexes.:" << endl;
}
static void sane_func_2() {
  scoped_lock l{mut_b, mut_a};
  cout << "sane f2 got both mutexes." << endl;
}

int main() {
  {
    thread t1{sane_func_1};
    thread t2{sane_func_2};
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }
}
```

I'm getting E0441, C2955, and C2514 errors on the `scoped_lock` lines within `sane_func_1()` and `sane_func_2()`. The compiler is complaining about argument lists and constructors for these 2 lines. I'm hoping it's just a syntax error I overlooked or something that's fallen out of the appropriate scope.

Comment: [live at wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VRk4Dxne2EVy8nwT), I don't see any errors.

Comment: I get very different errors [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/s5Aacd)

Comment: Those error codes look like Visual Studio error codes. Please share the VS version you are using along with the complete error messages.

Comment: AFAIK, Visual Studio doesn't yet support all of C++17, both in library features and in language features. You are probably running into one of those cases

Comment: `using namespace std;
using namespace chrono_literals;` - bad habit.

Comment: I'm running version 15.6.6

Comment: VS2017 doesn't support class template argument deduction yet, replace `scoped_lock` with `scoped_lock<std::mutex, std::mutex>` and your code should compile.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;` is, on the other hand, not a bad habit.

Comment: @Yakk did I say it was? (Especially if used inside a restricted scope).. But, I'd personally stick to importing specific types/functions, rather than entire namespaces..